# SSH to other Azure Linux Servers from jump server

Tags: ssh, azure, cloud

I provisioned a stack of VM's and during the process I elected to create a jump server. Now I am on the jump server trying to connect to other machines via SSH but I keep getting an error stating that 'Permission denied (publickey)'

The machines are running Ubuntu and this is on Microsoft Azure.

During the creation I did specify a public key that I already had from a ppk file, loaded into puttygen to copy it. I assume the other VM's have this as well. Not sure how to get into them.

Comment: I created a new file on the jump server and pasted the key from puttygen, then specified that key using -i flag in ssh, but then it asks for a passphrase?!?

Comment: You should be using an ssh agent for this, not copying a private key around. Look into pageant - it's a Windows equivalent of the classic Linux/UNIX ssh-agent.

Comment: I tried creating a new public/private key pair. Then re-provisioning the stack, this time using the public key. I am on the jump server, verified my public key matches the key inside .ssh/authorized_keys and it STILL won't let me into the other machines. It does prompt for a passphrase just like it does when I access the jump server, I type the same one and it keeps repeatedly asking me for passphrase. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-rdma-cluster/#passwordless-ssh-trust-on-a-centos-cluster) provides a [github link](https://github.com/tanewill/utils/blob/master/user_authentication.sh) that provides code useful in setting up passwordless ssh between nodes. You might need to recreate your vms with a password enabled ssh if they don't already have that option.

Their example is for CentOS, but I think it can easily be modified to work on ubuntu.

```
#!/bin/bash
#for centos user must first install epel-release, sshpass, and nmap (sshpass and nmap are available from epel-release for CENTOS)

#usage ./authMe2.sh [username] [password] [internalIP prefix]
# ./authMe2.sh azureuser Azure@123 10.2.1
USER=$1
PASS=$2
IPPRE=$3
HEADNODE=`hostname`

mkdir -p .ssh
echo -e  'y\n' | ssh-keygen -f .ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''

echo 'Host *' >> .ssh/config
echo 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' >> .ssh/config
chmod 400 .ssh/config
chown azureuser:azureuser /home/azureuser/.ssh/config

nmap -sn $IPPRE.* | grep $IPPRE. | awk '{print $5}' > nodeips.txt
for NAME in `cat nodeips.txt`; do sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'hostname' >> nodenames.txt;done

NAMES=`cat nodenames.txt` #names from names.txt file
for NAME in $NAMES; do
    sshpass -p $PASS scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o    ConnectTimeout=2 /home/$USER/nodenames.txt $USER@$NAME:/home/$USER/
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME "mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh"
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME "echo -e  'y\n' | ssh-keygen -f .ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N ''"
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'touch /home/'$USER'/.ssh/config'
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'echo "Host *" >  /home/'$USER'/.ssh/config'
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'echo StrictHostKeyChecking no >> /home/'$USER'/.ssh/config'
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'chmod 400 /home/'$USER'/.ssh/config'
    cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
    sshpass -p $PASS scp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME:/home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa.pub .ssh/sub_node.pub

    for SUBNODE in `cat nodeips.txt`; do
            sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$SUBNODE 'mkdir -p .ssh'
            cat .ssh/sub_node.pub | sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$SUBNODE 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
    done
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'chmod 700 .ssh/'
    sshpass -p $PASS ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 $USER@$NAME 'chmod 640 .ssh/authorized_keys'

done
```